# Como remover um where do @Query no JPARepository do Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-jpa, hql

Estou usando Spring BOOT com o starter JPA e java 8 e possuo essa query no meu repository :

```
    @Query("select p from Product p where p.name like %:name% and p.costValue = :costValue and p.saleValue= :saleValue")
List<Product> findByExemple(@Param("name") String name, @Param("costValue") Float costValue, @Param("saleValue") Float saleValue);
```

Eu necessito que quando os parâmetro float vier nulo remover a condição ou trazer tudo, seria um % no campo de numero.

Exemplo:

Quando o parâmetro costValue vier nulo trazer todos. Sem a utilização de filtro seria como se fizesse a Query desta forma :

```
        @Query("select p from Product p where p.name like %:name% and p.saleValue= :saleValue")
List<Product> findByExemple(@Param("name") String name, @Param("costValue") Float costValue, @Param("saleValue") Float saleValue);
```

Comment: A solução mais rápida seria não utilizar `@Query` e sim montar um HQL ou Criteria com base na sua condicional

Comment: Ou até mesmo criar novos [query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) para considerar ou não a propriedade, mas eu não gosto muito dessa abordagem, prefiro minha primeira sugestão por deixar o código mais reutilizável

Comment: Eu nunca tinha utilizado HQL e com sua resposta dei uma pesquisada e achei a melhor abordagem. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais simples de alteração sem a utilização de hql conforme já citado seria colocar a condicional OR no seu select contemplando o caso nulo, ex:

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.name like %:name% and ( p.costValue = :costValue OR :costValue is null ) and p.saleValue= :saleValue")
List<Product> findByExemple(@Param("name") String name, @Param("costValue") Float costValue, @Param("saleValue") Float saleValue);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente obrigado pela ajuda!